# how to specify version of dependency in meson build?

Tags: c++, meson-build, subproject

I have two projects in C++, both using meson build. One is a subproject of the other:

`noise-status` is a dependency of `noise-service`

I'm importing the `noise-status` subproject with a wrap-file:

```
[wrap-git]
url = http://eng-server:9090/yxia/noise-status.git
revision = master
```

And in the `noise-service` meson build file, I'm specifying the version of this subproject that I want to be used (`noise-service` has tags up to 0.5.0):

```
noise_status_dep = dependency('noise-status', required: false, version: '0.2.0')
```

But this apparently doesn't work, it always pull the latest version of `noise-status` as a subproject. How should I modify this setup for pulling a specific version of the subproject?

Comment: What does `version: '<=0.2.0'` yield?

Comment: it still uses the most recent version of the dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrap file specifies the imported version in your case. Currently it will choose `master`. You must change `revision = master` to the tag you want to import.

From the [manual](https://mesonbuild.com/Wrap-dependency-system-manual.html):

> `revision` - name of the revision to checkout. Must be either: a valid
> value (such as a git tag) for the VCS's checkout command, or (for git)
> `head` to track upstream's default branch. Required.

So, if you want the tag `0.2.0` change your `wrap` file to:

```
[wrap-git]
url = http://eng-server:9090/yxia/noise-status.git
revision = 0.2.0
```

The `dependency` declaration would still work this way:

```
noise_status_dep = dependency('noise-status', required: false)
```

If you add the `provide` keyword as well, you can declare an individual name which you can reference in the dependency declaration, such as:

```
[wrap-git]
url = http://eng-server:9090/yxia/noise-status.git
revision = 0.2.0

[provide]
dependency_names = noise-status-0.2.0
```

Then you can declare a dependency with that name:

```
noise_status_dep = dependency('noise-status-0.2.0', required: false)
```

Comment: It gives the following errors
```error: pathspec '0.2.0' did not match any file(s) known to git```
```fatal: couldn't find remote ref 0.2.0```

how should I tag the original ```noise-status``` project (i used ```version```)?

Comment: is `0.2.0` really a valid tag label in your git repository?

Comment: The wrap file does not really care for version numbers, only git's tags: `revision = <a_tag_label>`
Quoting the manual:

revision - name of the revision to checkout. Must be either: a valid value (such as a git tag) for the VCS's checkout command, or (for git) head to track upstream's default branch. Required.

Comment: I understand now! I should use git tags to correctly specify revisions